# JQuery adding object function using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an object's function to a button that is created when some conditions are met. Does it matter if I have the var I'm trying to change outside document.ready?

```
var myvar = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myobj = {
  changeMyVar: function(){ myvar++;}
 }
...
/* button id='my-button' is created in a div id='mydiv' */
...
 $('#mydiv').on('click', '#my-button', myobj.changeMyVar);
});
```

No function is attached to the button and no error is thrown. In fact, console.log(myobj.changeMyVar) returns undefined. What am I missing here?

Edit: I lied about no errors, I get a 'undefined is not a function' on the .on() line.

Thanks!

Edit2: After further analysis, I discovered a silly type-o in my original code. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Your Code should work. http://jsfiddle.net/3x5angew/

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating your issue in a fiddle, but it worked.

Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/7fjk3wxs/1/

This is what I used:

```
var myvar = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myobj = {
  changeMyVar: function(){ 
      myvar++;
      alert(myvar);
  }
 };


 $('#mydiv').on('click', '#my-button', myobj.changeMyVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After further analysis, I discovered a silly type-o in my original code. Thanks for the answers!